# listing existing joins in table of contents feature

Tags: python, attribute-joins, table, feature-class

I am looking for a way to use python in ArcGIS desktop to check and print out the joins that exist between tables and feature classes in my map rather than right-clicking, going to joins and relates and seeing what is joined to the feature classes.

Any idea on a python script that would print the joins that exist?  The rest of the coding I think I could figure out.

Comment: It sounds like you may be using ArcGIS for Desktop and wanting to use ArcPy but can you [edit] your question to make what you are using clear, please?

Comment: I would do this in ArcObjects, I don't think that arcpy would have the tools to allow you to find much information on joined/related tables.

Comment: Duplicate? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7703/can-join-be-detected-programmatically-by-arcpy and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66788/how-to-programatically-identify-the-joined-field-in-arcmap