# Can a Relate within an MXD be detected programmatically using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, layers, relates

I would like to know if it is possible detect relates in an MXD using arcpy.

Similar problem as the question below, but for relates instead of joins.

[Detecting Join programmatically using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7703/can-join-be-detected-programmatically-by-arcpy)

More specifically, relates listed in the "Joins & Relates" tab of the "Layer Properties" and not geodatabase "Relationship Classes".

I have checked the ArcGIS documentation and have done several Google searches without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, not without accessing arcobjects. You would need to install comtypes module to access the interface that would return that information.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.